# Python code is giving error

Tags: python, networking, cisco, cidr

My code is written below.
while running it is giving me the below error :

```
import sys
import numbers
import idlelib
import importlib        


(addrString, cidrString) = sys.argv[1].split('/')


 addr = addrString.split('.')
 cidr = int(cidrString)


 mask = [0, 0, 0, 0]
 for i in range(cidr):
 mask[i/8] = mask[i/8] + (1 << (7 - i % 8))


 net = []
 for i in range(4):
 net.append(int(addr[i]) & mask[i])


  broad = list(net)
  brange = 32 - cidr
  for i in range(brange):
  broad[3 - i/8] = broad[3 - i/8] + (1 << (i % 8))


   print ("Address:   ") , addrString
   print ("Netmask:   ") , ".".join(map(str, mask))
   print ("Network:   ") , ".".join(map(str, net))
   print ("Broadcast: ") , ".".join(map(str, broad))
```

getting the error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\solut\Desktop\subnet.py", line 7, in 
(addrString, cidrString) = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It depends upon what arguments you are passing to cidrstring.

Comment: What did you expect this line: `(addrString, cidrString) = sys.argv[2]` to do? And what arguments are you passing to this program?

Comment: Well! i am a quite new to this. IF you can update the code or let me know how to ..

Comment: Your line as it was written will take the second command line argument if it has exactly 2 characters and put each character into one of the variables. I doubt that is your intention.

Comment: Got this code from a friend. My intention is to create a code where i can give an IP address and it can calculate CIDR value for me

Comment: And now after your edit your code does not fit the error message anymore.

Comment: But i am still getting the same error message ..

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a list of (strings) arguments on the command-line.

You're probably running your script with too few arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending more than one argument, you have to validate sys.argv first

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
   addrString = sys.argv[1]
   cidrString = sys.argv[2]
   print(addrString)
   print(cidrString)
```